# Why isn't drag&drop working with QSqlQueryModel?

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop, qsqlquery, qsqlquerymodel

I'm trying to make a interface that's easy to use. I have 2 list one of them list of device already using and the other one is unused ones. So, I'm trying to do add drag and drop feature. Like this.
[image]

But mine is like this. I cannot drag or drop with QSqlQueryModel.(I used listview)

[image]

The codes i wrote for listview like this.

```
ui->listViewMusteri->setDragEnabled(true);
    ui->listViewMusteri->setAcceptDrops(true);
    ui->listViewMusteri->setDropIndicatorShown(true);
    ui->listViewMusteri->setDefaultDropAction(Qt::MoveAction);

    ui->listViewToplam->setDragEnabled(true);
    ui->listViewToplam->setAcceptDrops(true);
    ui->listViewToplam->setDropIndicatorShown(true);
    ui->listViewToplam->setDefaultDropAction(Qt::MoveAction);
```

```
void InformationMusteriDialog::fillListViews() {
    QSqlQueryModel *model = new QSqlQueryModel();
    if(database.isOpen()) {
        QSqlQuery* qry = new QSqlQuery(database);

        qry->prepare("SELECT `Cihaz Seri No` From `cihazisim`");
        qry -> exec();
        model->setQuery(*qry);

        ui->listViewToplam->setModel(model);
    }
}
```

Please let me know if more information or explanation is required.

Comment: [The docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/model-view-programming.html#using-drag-and-drop-with-item-views) say that you have to support DnD by your models. You should check the mentioned methods carefully, that they have correct implementation. The docs say for instance: _Note that the model will typically need to provide implementations of the QAbstractItemModel::insertRows() and QAbstractItemModel::setData() functions_, and by default e.g.[QSqlQueryModel::insertRows](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemmodel.html#insertRows) returns `false`.

Comment: @absolute.madness yes you're right but i cant even drag the items. I set the dragEnabled true. I dont know why.